# How to use an external configuration file in an with nodeJS CLI Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I have a NodeJs CLI program. How to load an external configuration files in the program. Just like `webpack-cli`, it allows the users to customize the `webpack.config.js` file. How does it read the user's `webpack.config.js` file. 


 **I tried the following, but it didn't work**

```
require(path.resolve(process.cwd() ,  'some.config.js'));
// Cannot find module 'E:\code\some.config.js'
```

Comment: are you sure your file is at E:\code\some.config.js?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-config

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('cli-config').run({dirname: __dirname, cmdTree: require(__dirname + '/lib'});
```